# how to manage concurrency inside async method

Tags: c#, concurrency, .net-core

I have a .net core API call that  takes an object, checks the database to see if it exists and then saves it to (Mongo) database.

My problem is that sometimes these requests come from a queue or perhaps from the user double clicking on a button, so the version that is saved is not necessarily the version that is fetched (because the update doesn't happen straight after the get).

My question is:  how should I manage this fetch and then update within an async method (given that you can't use lock)

**This is the api method**

```
public async Task<NotificationResponse> Any(Notification request)
{
    try
    {
        //want to put a lock around these somehow.....
        ICdsDeclarationData declaration = await m_DataProvider.GetImportDeclaration(request.LocalReferenceNumber); //returns data with rowVersion number
        //do some other stuff                

        await m_DataProvider.UpsertImportDeclaration(declaration, request.LocalReferenceNumber); //save to DB
    }
    catch { /* ... */ }
}
```

And inside the data provider Upsert method we have

```
private void IncrementAndCheckRowVersion(IRowVersionable newPoco, IRowVersionable storedPoco, string uniqueIdentifier)
{
    newPoco.RowVersion = newPoco.RowVersion + 1;
    if (newPoco.RowVersion <= storedPoco.RowVersion)
    {
        Logger.Warn(x => x.Message($"Concurrency violation detected for [{uniqueIdentifier}] - new record rowversion: [{newPoco.RowVersion}] stored record rowversion: [{storedPoco.RowVersion}]"));
        throw new ConcurrencyException($"Row version mismatch for [{uniqueIdentifier}]");
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't think in terms of async / lock etc - in reality database is always concurrent, so sooner or later you will have two clients on separate machines doing the same task (think about horizontal scaling as a sample). so you should just live  with it and handle concurrency in a business way - notify user, or restart transaction, or merge results automatically etc

Comment: I think in principal you are probably right, but in this specific implementation we are attaching logging data to a message every time it is sent, so we can get errors even when there is only one person calling it (if for instance they double click a button say)

Comment: The point of @Lanorkin's comment is that it's better to solve the concurrency problem using a logical solution like optimistic concurrency with retries; that will solve concurrency issues regardless of scenario - it fixes horizontal scaling **and** double-clicking a button. If you solve the concurrency problem using something like a `SemaphoreSlim` (an async-compatible lock), then that *only* solves the double-clicking scenario and not the horizontal scaling scenario.

Comment: use a manualreseteventslim

Comment: What is the desirable behavior? Do you want to serialize the concurrent operations, or you want to abort the operation that was originated by the second click?